# Linking error while trying to build ffmpeg source code to make independent library

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg source code on ubuntu 10.1 linux machine with gcc version 4.4.3.

I am interested in making av_transcode() function in ffmpeg.c available", So I have commented out the main function of ffmpeg.c.

gcc $(LD_LIBRARY_PATHS) -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-E  -o ffmpeg_g ffmpeg.o cmdutils.o -lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lz -pthread -lm -lx264 -lm -lasound -lasound -lasound -ldl

I am getting below linking errors

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The same behavior is observed On my MacOS (snow leopard) as well.

SO putting the question short, How can I tell gcc compiler that I am building this source code to make library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc -shared` if you're trying to build a shared library, otherwise just use `ar` to bundle the compiled objects together.

But you really should go read [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (PDF) and lots of other documentation, so that you understand why the above will sometimes fail without `-fPIC` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, The document was helpful in understanding libraries creation.